# Share a electrical disconnect heat pump/car charger

Tags: electrical

Outside my house I have a electrical disconnect that had 60amp 240v going into it, previous owner went overkill for his big Tesla.

Last year I used the disconnect to add a much needed heat pump, I changed the breaker to 25 amps for what it was rated for, my question is. Would it be allowed to add a 30amp car charger and put back the original 60 amp breaker and to share the disconnect?

Comment: What make/model is the existing disconnect?

Comment: Before doing anything, I would double-check the wire size going from the panel to the disconnect. 60A is an extremely standard size of disconnect, often used with much smaller circuits because a disconnect is often needed for anywhere from 20A - 60A and this way you only need to stock one type of disconnect. If the previous owner actually had a 60A breaker then it *should* be 60A-rated wire, but it pays to make sure. Could have played some funny games with 60A breaker + 60A disconnect + wire rated for 40A + program the Tesla EVSE to only think it has 40A available.

Comment: It's for sure either 6-8awg size. It's thick and stranded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to share the disconnect without separate overcurrent protection (breaker) for each circuit.

However, most people who slap 60A charging on their car, didn't bother to do a Load Calculation to assure their house could handle that.  They just slap it on the house and don't even think about it.   So you should not go "... and therefore my house has 60A to spare".  That NEC Article 220 Load Calculation is the place to start.

To split the circuit, you can either have a separate breaker in the supplying panel, or install a subpanel at the disconnect location. Note some disconnects are actually 2-space subpanels, and support quadplex breakers.

Comment: It's a small house, and I have 200amps coming in. But in theory could I change the disconnect that's outside for a small sub panel?  I'm trying to avoid running a new cable and having 2 disconnects next to each other outside.

Comment: @DennisMiller The disconnect can be a breaker in a subpanel right next to the outdoor unit. As long as it can be locked out (most breakers can) and is visible and readily accessible from the AC.